# Is it possible to get plot from panda dataframe includes missing data by Heatmap with especial color?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, missing-data

I was wondering if I can get all plots of columns in panda dataframe in one-window via heatmap in 24x20 self-made matrix-model-square which I designed to map every 480 values of each column(which means 1-cycle) by mapping them inside of it through all cycles. The challenging point is I want to show missing data by using especial color which is out of color range of colormap `cmap ='coolwarm'`

I already tried by using `df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` make sure that all `inf` convert to `nan` and then by using `df = df.replace(0,np.nan)` before `sns.heatmap(df, vmin=-1, vmax=+1, cmap ='coolwarm'` I can recognize missing values via white color since in `cmap ='coolwarm'` white color represents `nan/inf` in this interval `[vmin=-1, vmax=+1]` after applying above-mentioned instructions however it has 2 problem:

First in case that you have `0` in your dataset it will be shown like missing data by white color too and you can't distinguish between `inf/nan` and `0` in columns. Second problem is you can't even differentiate between nan and inf values!

I also tried `mask=df.isnull()` inside `sns.heatmap()` by specifying a mask, where data will not be shown for those cells whose mask values are True but it covers again `0` based on this answer [GH375](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/375). I'm not sure the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488251/plotting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-which-contains-nan-values?rq=1) mentioned by @Scotty1- is right solution for my case by adding `marker` to interpolate the values by `newdf = newdf.interpolate()`.
Is it good idea to filter missing data by subsetting :

```
import math
df = df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: math.isnan(x))]
df = df[df['a'] == float('inf')]
```

My scripts are following however in for-loop I couldn't get proper output due to in each cycle it prints plot each of them 3 times in different intervals eg. it prints `A` left then again it prints `A` under the name of `B` and `C` in middle and right in-one-window. Again it prints `B` 3-times instead once and put it middle and in the end it prints `C` 3-times instead of once and put in right side it put in middle and left!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#extract the parameters and put them in lists based on id_set
df = pd.read_csv('D:\SOF.TXT', header=None)
id_set = df[df.index % 4 == 0].astype('int').values
a = df[df.index % 4 == 1].values
b = df[df.index % 4 == 2].values
c = df[df.index % 4 == 3].values
data = {'A': a[:,0], 'B': b[:,0], 'C': c[:,0] }
#main_data contains all the data
main_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C'], index = id_set[:,0])  



#next iteration create all plots, change the numer of cycles
cycles = int(len(main_data)/480)
print(cycles)
for i in main_data:
    try:
        os.mkdir(i)
    except:
        pass
    min_val = main_data[i].min()
    min_nor = -1
    max_val = main_data[i].max()
    max_nor = 1
    for cycle in range(1):             #iterate thriugh all cycles range(1) by ====> range(int(len(main_data)/480))
        count =  '{:04}'.format(cycle)
        j = cycle * 480
        ordered_data = mkdf(main_data.iloc[j:j+480][i])
        csv = print_df(ordered_data)
        #Print .csv files contains matrix of each parameters by name of cycles respectively
        csv.to_csv(f'{i}/{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)            
        if 'C' in i:
            min_nor = -40
            max_nor = 150
            #Applying normalizayion for C between [-40,+150]
            new_value = normalize(main_data.iloc[j:j+480][i].values, min_val, max_val, -40, 150)
            n_cbar_kws = {"ticks":[-40,150,-20,0,25,50,75,100,125]}
        else:
            #Applying normalizayion for A,B between    [-1,+1]
            new_value = normalize(main_data.iloc[j:j+480][i].values, min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
            n_cbar_kws = {"ticks":[-1.0,-0.75,-0.50,-0.25,0.00,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.0]}    
        Sections = mkdf(new_value)
        df = print_df(Sections)
        #Plotting parameters by using HeatMap
        plt.figure()
        sns.heatmap(df, vmin=min_nor, vmax=max_nor, cmap ='coolwarm', cbar_kws=n_cbar_kws)                             
        plt.title(i, fontsize=12, color='black', loc='left', style='italic')
        plt.axis('off')
        #Print .PNG iamges contains HeatMap plots of each parametersby name of cycles respectively
        plt.savefig(f'{i}/{i}{count}.png')  



    #plotting all columns ['A','B','C'] in-one-window side by side


    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3 , figsize=(20,10))
    plt.subplot(131)
    sns.heatmap(df, vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap ="coolwarm", cbar=True , cbar_kws={"ticks":[-1.0,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.00,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]})
    fig.axes[-1].set_ylabel('[MPa]', size=20) #cbar_kws={'label': 'Celsius'}
    plt.title('A', fontsize=12, color='black', loc='left', style='italic')
    plt.axis('off')

    plt.subplot(132)
    sns.heatmap(df, vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap ="coolwarm", cbar=True , cbar_kws={"ticks":[-1.0,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.00,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0]})
    fig.axes[-1].set_ylabel('[Mpa]', size=20) #cbar_kws={'label': 'Celsius'}
    #sns.despine(left=True)
    plt.title('B', fontsize=12, color='black', loc='left', style='italic')
    plt.axis('off')

    plt.subplot(133)
    sns.heatmap(df, vmin=-40, vmax=150, cmap ="coolwarm" , cbar=True , cbar_kws={"ticks":[-40,150,-20,0,25,50,75,100,125]}) 
    fig.axes[-1].set_ylabel('[°C]', size=20) #cbar_kws={'label': 'Celsius'}
    #sns.despine(left=True)
    plt.title('C', fontsize=12, color='black', loc='left', style='italic')
    plt.axis('off')


    plt.suptitle(f'Analysis of data in cycle Nr.: {count}', color='yellow', backgroundcolor='black', fontsize=48, fontweight='bold')
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.7, bottom=0.3, left=0.05, right=0.95, hspace=0.2, wspace=0.2)
    #plt.subplot_tool()
    plt.savefig(f'{i}/{i}{i}{count}.png') 
    plt.show()
```

my data frame looks like following:

```
          A          B            C
0      2.291171  -2.689658  -344.047912
10     2.176816  -4.381186  -335.936524
20     2.291171  -2.589725  -342.544885
30     2.176597  -6.360999     0.000000
40     2.577268  -1.993412  -344.326376
50     9.844076  -2.690917  -346.125859
60     2.061782  -2.889378  -346.375655
```

Here below is overview of my dataset sample from .TXT file: [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dQD_CARJ00-olkK_h7Sl8Q2lORX-d6QF/view?usp=sharing)
in case that you want to check out with missing data values please change the last 3 values of end of text file to nan/inf and save it and debug it.

```
7590                  7590
0                     nan
7.19025828418         nan
-1738.000075          inf
```

I'd like to visualise a large pandas-dataframe includes 3 columns `columns=['A','B','C']` via heatmaps in-one-window. This dataframe has two types of variables: strings (`nan` or `inf`) and floats.
I want the heatmap to show missing data cells inside of matrix-squared-model by fixed colors like `nan` by black and `inf` by silver or gray, and the rest of the dataframe as a normal heatmap, with the floats in a scale of `cmap ='coolwarm'`.

Here is image of desired output when there is no nan/inf in dataset:

[image: desired image]

I'm looking forward to hearing from those people they are dealing with these issues.